# AWS CloudWatch triggering CodePipeline execution works in one account, but not in another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline

we use two AWS accounts, **one for development (dev)** and **one for production (prod)** and **one main AWS CodePipeline**.

This main pipeline - **running in prod at the moment** - is building our application into a Docker image and pushing it to the ECR repository in dev and from there a separate pipeline should be triggered to start a deployment to ECS in dev. 
If the deployment is successful in ECS dev, there is a manual approval step in pipeline 1 to promote the container to ECR prod which triggers deployment to ECS prod.

Now there is the issue:

We're using CloudWatch event rules to trigger the two deployment pipelines and the rule is checking for a **"PutImage"** event coming from CloudTrail.

**This works only for the images that get put into the ECR in prod, but NOT in dev.** The rules simply do not trigger, allthough I can see the events in Cloudtrail in dev.

What could be the issue? Using Terraform, the setup for dev and prod is identical.

I first thought the pipeline, running in prod, might need to be able to send events to dev (https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/cloudwatch-events-adds-cross-account-event-delivery-support/), but this is unlikely, because I can see the events in CloudTrail dev already.

Is it maybe because the pipeline itself is running in prod?

> Pipeline 1: Application git -> Docker build & push to dev ECR - if deployment in dev
>   successful: manual approval -> push to prod ECR
>
> Pipeline 2 (NOT TRIGGERED) 
>   Alibi git source -> get newest image tag from ECR
>   dev, output imagedefinitions.json -> input imagedefinitions.json,
>   deploy to ECS dev
>
> Pipeline 3 (TRIGGERED CORRECTLY AFTER MANUAL APPROVAL) 
>   Alibi git source ->
>   get newest image tag from ECR pro, output imagedefinitions.json ->
>   input imagedefinitions.json, deploy to ECS prod

We're using an alibi git source because Codepipeline requires a source at the beginning; so we're checking out a repo, but getting the newest image tag from ECR is the important step here.

The Cloudwatch event rule that **works for prod, but not for dev**:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "latest_image" {
  name        = "latest-image"
  description = "Capture push to ECR"

  event_pattern = <<PATTERN
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ecr"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "ecr.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "PutImage"
    ],
    "awsRegion": [
      "${var.region}"
    ],
    "requestParameters": {
      "repositoryName": [
        "${var.application_name}"
      ],
      "registryId": [
        "${var.account_id}"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Confirming few things here: 1. Does all the Pipelines 1, 2 and 3 are in prod account? 2. Where is the CloudWatch rule created (Prod or Dev) 3. Where is the ECR repository locates? (Prod or Dev) 4. Pipeline 2 is not triggering properly is that correct?